# Python: trouble inheriting from multiple parent classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a subclass that needs to inherit from two parents differing only in methods and a single property. When instantiating this class, I'm getting an error stating I'm using to many parameters. When removing a param it says I'm not using enough.

### Ball

```
class Ball:
    """
    base class for bouncing objects
    """
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius):
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius

    def update(self):
        # bounce at edges.  TODO: Fix sticky edges
        if self.position.x < 0 + self.radius or self.position.x > self.bounds[0] - self.radius: # screen width
            self.velocity.x *= -1
        if self.position.y < 0 + self.radius or self.position.y > self.bounds[1] - self.radius: # screen height
            self.velocity.y *= -1
        self.position += self.velocity

    def draw(self, screen, pygame):
        # cast x and y to int for drawing
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, [int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y)], self.radius)
```

### BouncingBall

```
class BouncingBall(Ball):
    """
    ball effected by gravity
    """
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight):
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius)
        self.weight = weight

    def update(self):
```

### KineticBall

```
class KineticBall(Ball):
    """
    A ball that collides with other collidable balls using simple elastic circle collision
    """
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, object_list):
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius)
        self.object_list = object_list
```

### KineticBouncing

```
class KineticBouncing(BouncingBall, KineticBall):
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list):
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list)
```

### ball => KineticBouncing

```
# super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list)
TypeError: __init__() takes 7 positional arguments but 8 were given

ball = KineticBouncing(SCREEN_SIZE, Vector2(50, 50), Vector2(3, 3), [255, 0, 255], 10, -1, object_list)
```

### Lets try something else...

So this is confusing.. instead I find [Python3 Multiple Inheritance](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php) which I'm sure will solve my problem. Just use the parents name + **init** instead of super() right?

### KineticBouncing

```
class KineticBouncing(BouncingBall, KineticBall):
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list):
        BouncingBall.__init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight)
        KineticBall.__init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, object_list)
```

### ball => KinetBouncing

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "draw.py", line 99, in <module>
#    main()
#  File "draw.py", line 61, in main
#    debug_create_balls(object_list)
#  File "draw.py", line 43, in debug_create_balls
#    ball = KineticBouncing(SCREEN_SIZE, Vector2(50, 50), Vector2(3, 3), [255, 0, 255], 10, -1, object_list)
#  File "/home/adam/Desktop/web_dev/lambda_school/python/Python-OOP-Toy/src/ball.py", line 115, in __init__
#    BouncingBall.__init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight)
#  File "/home/adam/Desktop/web_dev/lambda_school/python/Python-OOP-Toy/src/ball.py", line 33, in __init__
#    super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius)
#TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'object_list'

ball = KineticBouncing(SCREEN_SIZE, Vector2(50, 50), Vector2(3, 3), [255, 0, 255], 10, -1, object_list)
```

So how in the world am I supposed to inherit from these two parent classes?

Comment: Can you add the code for your Ball class?

Comment: Read [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), which goes over what `super` actually does and how to leverage it for easy multiple inheritance.

Comment: @MoxieBall - Ball is now at the top of the question. @ Patrick Haugh - Will do.

Comment: I believe your Ball class needs to call `super().__init__()` as well - regardless, that link from Patrick should be pretty useful to you.

Comment: I just want to say that this OOP structure is not fitting well. Maybe read someting about Mixins classes. Because in actual situation You are 2 times initializing the Ball-part of class.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you should redesign your use of classes a bit.  The immediate problem is that `super()` resolves to the first parent class of the *object* in question (`self`), rather than the parent class of the `__init__` method you're in at the time.

When you try to initialize your `KineticBouncing` object, you invoke `KineticBouncing.super().__init__()`.  This explicitly calls the `__init__` methods of its two parent classes.  When it first calls the one in `BouncingBall`, the first active statement is

```
    super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius)
```

I believe that you expect this to call `Ball.__init__`; that's not how `super` works.  Instead, it resolves `super` based on the object, which is of class `KineticBouncing`.  So ... what is `super` to `KineticBouncing`?  Note that between the two `__init__` calls as you've written them, you *have* to be wrong at least once.

I'll leave you to read the links provided in the comments.  These will help you think in terms of Python's inheritance structure.  With what you've posted, I think you'll have little trouble handling the switch; you merely picked a hierarchy model from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*args` in all your parent's init

```
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print ('IN Ball')

class BouncingBall(Ball):
    """
    ball effected by gravity
    """ 
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, *args):
        print ('IN BouncingBall')
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, *args)
        self.weight = weight

class KineticBall(Ball):
    """
    A ball that collides with other collidable balls using simple elastic circle collision
    """ 
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, object_list, *args):
        print ('IN KineticBall') 
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, *args)
        self.object_list = object_list

class KineticBouncing(BouncingBall, KineticBall):
    def __init__(self, bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list):
        print ('IN KineticBouncing')
        super().__init__(bounds, position, velocity, color, radius, weight, object_list)
```

Now on creating a new kinetic bouncing ball

```
ball = KineticBouncing('SCREEN_SIZE', 'Vector2(50, 50)', 'Vector2(3, 3)', [255, 0, 255], 10, -1, 'object_list')
IN KineticBouncing
IN BouncingBall
IN KineticBall
IN Ball
```